# Cannot get projections to work

Tags: google-shared-contacts

For a while I've been trying to make projections work for a google contacts api call (v3). My reference is: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#projection-values

From OAuth 2.0 Playground (as well as my real app) I'm trying:

www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=3.0&max-results=10
www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?v=3.0&max-results=10

Actually I'm only interested in contacts (with) mail:
www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/property-email?v=3.0&max-results=10

No matter what I do, I always seem to get the FULL projection returned.

Am I missing somewhat here?

Kind regards,
Joris